# setDefaultTimeZone does not work

Tags: ios, sdk, nsdate, nstimezone

I only found very old entries about setDefaultTimeZone in iOS SDK, but no solution for the problem, that setDefaultTimeZone simply does not do anything.

```
NSTimeZone *germanTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:germanTimeZone];
NSLog(@"Berlin time: %@", [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:nil]);
```

This should result in something like:

```
Berlin time: 2014-06-30 15:58:34 +0200
```

But it results simly to:

```
Berlin time: 2014-06-30 15:58:34 +0000
```

Thank you in advance for any hint or solution.

**Edit:**
Ok, below is my working code.

```
NSTimeZone *germanTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:germanTimeZone];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
NSLog(@"Time: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: Use an `NSDateFormatter` to print the date in the desired format. `NSDate` objects represent absolute points in time and are independent of timezones (or anything else for that matter)

Comment: @spassas that is not true. The value of NSDate *will change* if you change the default timezone. Tested in simulator and playground.

Comment: @Dan "NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone" from the [NSDate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/)

Comment: @spassas I'm not sure what that NSDate documentation reference is refuting here, but you can try it yourself. An NSDate value *will change* if you change the timezone. Of course, it doesn't *contain* timezone data, but the value of the date will change.

Comment: @Dan Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650443/nsdate-behaviour-when-saving-to-plist/24650824#24650824) for a related discussion. Logging an `NSDate` will print the _description_ of the object and the output can be quite arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSTimeZone* UTC = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:UTC];
```

And to print use an NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the above needs a specified dateformat, i think, otherwise the output would be empty. I add my working code above.

Comment: @Sven, I'm glad you got it working. If this is a correct answer, can you mark it as such?