# NSDate behaviour when saving to plist

Tags: ios, nsdate, plist, nsdatecomponents, nstimezone

I am creating a date from [NSdate date] and saving it to plist, Here is how I am creating a date

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
   // [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];


    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger day    = [weekdayComponents day];
    NSInteger month  = [weekdayComponents month]; 
    NSInteger year   = [weekdayComponents year];

    NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [timeZoneComps setDay:day];
    [timeZoneComps setMonth:month];
    [timeZoneComps setYear:year];
    [timeZoneComps setHour:00];
    [timeZoneComps setMinute:00];
    [timeZoneComps setSecond:01];    


    NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [d setObject:date forKey:@"my-date"];

    [d writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

I have tested few cases

**Case 1: without setting timezone to NSCalendar object gregorian above(by default it will take local time zone) and setting time zone in device to india, I saved the date to plist and this is what I got**

NSLog of date shows **CurrentDate:2014-07-08 18:30:01 +0000**

[image]

**Case 2: Now setting device time zone to san jose USA**

NSLog of date shows **2014-07-09 07:00:01 +0000**

[image]

**Case 3: Setting timezone of  NSCalendar object, gregorian above to "UTC", and setting time zone in device to India, this is what I got in plist**

NSLog of date shows **2014-07-09 00:00:01 +0000**

[image]

**Case 4: Setting device time to san jose USA**

NSLog of date shows **2014-07-09 00:00:01 +0000**

[image]

Can anybody please explain me what is happening in all these cases.

Regards
Ranjit.

Comment: +1 well structured question.  Do you get the same date/time in the console when you log the date object using: `NSLog(@"date=%@", date);`?

Comment: Thanks, In which case?\

Comment: Well the above `NSLog()` call will use `[NSDate description]` to print the date, which is the date in UTC.  Therefore you have proved the effects of setting dates with specific time zones and saving them in UTC, which is why the dates change in the plist.

Comment: @trojanfoe, when time zone is UTC and device time zone is san jose , why in plist it is 5:30:01am, I can understand for india region, because the offset it is UTC+5:30.

Comment: Err, I don't understand that to be honest.  It's possible there is an error in your code (you have the same time for both india and california, so something is wrong here).

Comment: ok, @trojanfoe, can you explain me about the time in first two cases?

Comment: @trojanfoe It takes a bit of time to understand fully, but the thing to keep in mind is that the time zone specified by `NSCalendar` will be used in calculating the final `NSDate` object.  The first two are implicit, and the second two are explicit.  However, the final string will always be Indian Standard Time.

Comment: As a follow up to that comment I suppose I can see why it should output differently, but there are probably circumstances surrounding the fact that it always outputs Indian Standard Time instead of the local device time zone (maybe it is cached during app launch, etc)

Comment: Hey @borrrden, thanks for the detailed information, I tested by uninstalling the app and running again, but then also I get same results, so I think your speculation doesnt hold true.

Comment: @HotLicks, So what you suggest?

Comment: @trojanfoe, if you think, I have made any misatke in my code, if you get time, please test out, and let me know what results you get

Comment: I'm looking at it again.  What's unclear is what the original NSDate object was.  You should have NSLogged that along with dumping the plist date.  I'm thinking the plist is saved as UTC but you're logging different UTC times.

Comment: @HotLicks, no, I have shown all the 4 cases, with UTC and without UTC

Comment: You modified your code each time, so we don't know what it was for a given case.  And you don't, with each plist snapshot, have the NSLog of your NSDate object, so we know what the NSDate *really* was.

Comment: ok, I will update my question for the logs

Comment: Aha!  What you're seeing is probably the UTC time in the plist being converted to your Mac's local time by plist display function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57017/discussion-between-ranjit-and-hot-licks).

Comment: @HotLicks, if its that, can you test in your machine and let me know whether you get same results

Comment: @HotLicks Has a good point.  Open the plist in a text editor if you can and see how it is really saved.  The plist editor might be converting it from a number to a string on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the way you are handling `NSDate`.  Once you convert something into an `NSDate` then you lose all time zone information, and when you write it to the plist it will be written in *your current time zone* as it is converted back into a string.  So let's go through the scenarios one by one.

All scenarios follow this flow
NSDate -> NSDateComponents -> NSDate -> String

1)
NSDate: 2014-07-09 XX:XX:XX **IST** -> NSDateComponents 2014-07-09 00:00:01 **IST** -> NSDate 2014-07-09 00:00:01 **IST** -> 09-Jul-2014 12:00:01 am

2) 
NSDate: 2014-07-09 XX:XX:XX **PST** -> NSDateComponents 2014-07-09 00:00:01 **PST** -> NSDate 2014-07-09 12:30:01 **IST** -> 09-Jul-2014 12:30:01 pm

3)
NSDate: 2014-07-09 XX:XX:XX **UTC** -> NSDateComponents: 2014-07-09 00:00:01 **UTC** -> NSDate: 2014-07-09 05:30:01 **IST** -> 09-Jul-2014 5:30:01 am

4)
Same as 3 since you manually specified the time zone

Just remember that `NSDate` *does not care about time zones*.  It is just a point in time.  2014-07-09 00:00:01 **UTC** and 2014-07-09 05:30:01 **IST** are the *exact* same time in terms of `NSDate` (426556801 seconds ahead of 2001-01-01 00:00:00 GMT).  The reason why they differ in the plist is because you are choosing (implicitly) the local time representation of your `NSDate`.  If you need more control, use `NSDateFormatter`.

**EDIT** Come to think of it you could argue that the results should be different, but the way that `NSDate` outputs to a plist is proprietary so it looks like for some reason it keeps using Indian Standard Time.  Speculation could include maybe that you didn't kill your app between setting the time zone or something.

**SECOND EDIT** Actually I'm interested in what the raw plist is holding.  You are using an editor to view it, and it might be converting it to your **Mac's** local time when displaying it.

Comment: Hey @borrrden, thanks for the detailed information, I tested by uninstalling the app and running again, but then also I get same results, so I think your speculation doesnt hold true.

Comment: you say that for more control use NSDateFromatter, but where does that come into picture, bcoz, I am saving only dates, I have not converted them to strings

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` represents an **absolute point in time** and has nothing to do with timezones. What you're seeing and logging is the `NSDate` **description** which is fairly arbitrary across varying situations and useful **only** for debugging according to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/description)

> The representation is useful for debugging only.
>
> There are a number of options to aquire a formated string for a date
>   including: date formatters (see NSDateFormatter and Data Formatting
>   Guide), and the NSDate methods descriptionWithLocale:,
>   dateWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:, and
>   descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:

So, you can get your `NSDate` as stored since it's independent of any timezone information and use `NSCalendar` or `NSDateFormatter` to make all the conversions necessary to your app.

Comment: So do you mean that if my app is used by an US user, then the plist will contain 5:30:01 am for dates he/she store?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it does not make any difference for you. The `NSDate` will always point to the same point in time. So, as I wrote above, you just retrieve it and translate it to your desired format with the use of `NSCalendar`or `NSDateFormatter`

Comment: So you say that, it doesnt matter whether the plist contains 5:30:01 or 12:30:01 right? because the second case is 12:30:01

Comment: I think that the answer by @borrrden wraps it up very nicely.